# Get users NT Credentials in Winform App

Tags: c#, winforms, credentials, networkcredentials

I have a winform app that requires me to check whether a page exists on our Wiki or not. However, that query requires a users NetWork credentials to be passed.

I don't want to hardcode my credentials, and I don't want users to have to manipulate the App.config everytime someone else uses it (there's also the issue of them having to expose their password in the App.Config). Is there a way I can get the current user's NT credentials? I don't need to see it (that would be an obvious security issue), I just need it for the following line of code:

```
HttpWebRequest WikiPageRequest;
WikiPageRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "dom");
//maybe do something like this
WikiPageRequest.Credentials = GetNTCredentials();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using [CredentialCache.DefaultCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? That seems to get you the current logged in users credential.

Comment: Or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. Only works for NTLM/Negotiate/Kerberos.

Comment: This credential will work if the site is on IIS and uses "Windows Authentication".

Answer (score 0):

If by "wiki", you mean a deployment of MediaWiki, then sadly you need user id and password.

Unfortunately you cannot get it from Windows, because, even the Windows OS itself *does not know* the password. It just stores a hash of the password.

By the way, why dont you ask for user id/password for wiki each time the user starts the app?